# .NET MAUI - SQLite database reports 0 tables but contains tables when checked with DB Browser

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, maui

I’m developing a .NET MAUI application and I’m trying to use an existing SQLite database file (slagalicaLite.sqlite) in my project. I’ve added the SQLite file to my project and set its build action to EmbeddedResource.

Here’s my Constants.cs file:

```
namespace SlagalicaDS.Utilities
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string DatabaseFilename = "slagalicaLite.sqlite";
        public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;
        public static string DatabasePath =>
            Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename);
    }
}
```

And here’s my App.xaml.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using SlagalicaDS.Pages;
using SQLite;
using System.Reflection;
using SlagalicaDS.Utilities;

namespace SlagalicaDS
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static SQLite.SQLiteConnection Database;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new HomePage();
        }
    }
}
```

In my HomePage constructor, I’m initializing the SQLite connection and displaying a message indicating whether the connection was successful:

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        App.Database = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(SlagalicaDS.Utilities.Constants.DatabasePath, SlagalicaDS.Utilities.Constants.Flags);
        labelTitle.Text = "Database connection initialized successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        labelTitle.Text = $"Failed to initialize database connection: {ex.Message}";
    }
}
```

I also have a method that checks if the database file exists in the app’s data directory and copies it from the embedded resources if it doesn’t:

```
public void CheckAndCopyDatabase()
{
    var dbPath = SlagalicaDS.Utilities.Constants.DatabasePath;
    if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SlagalicaDS.slagalicaLite.sqlite");
        FileStream fileStream = File.Create(dbPath);
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    // Check if the file exists after copying
    if (File.Exists(dbPath))
    {
        labelTime.Text = "Database file copied successfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        labelTime.Text = "Failed to copy database file.";
    }
}
```

When I run my app, it displays “Database connection initialized successfully.” and “Database file copied successfully.”, which suggests that the SQLite connection is being initialized correctly and the database file is being copied correctly.

However, when I try to perform operations on the database, it reports that it contains 0 tables. But when I open the SQLite file with DB Browser for SQLite, it shows that the database contains 8 tables.

So, I realized that, even when if I change paramater of this line

`Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SlagalicaDS.slagalicaLite.sqlite");`

to something random like this

`assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("wfgewfeuiwfe.sqlite");`

it reports that connection is established

I’m not sure what’s going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Maybe fixing this is a hell of a job, so it does not matter whether I have to do it the other way I just want to have this done cause I am going insane.

Comment: I don't think that doing `new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(...)` creates the connection object but doesn't actually open the connection. You need to open it with `App.Database.Open();` for example. It's hard to tell since you don't tell us what `SQLite.SQLiteConnection` is or which version you are using. It looks like the Devart package, but that doesn't take flags like you are passing in here.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you provide me with some resources so I can learn how to implement an already existing SQLite database into a MAUI project?

Comment: Opening the sqlite connection probably created an empty DB. I guess you need to delete the existing destination file so that the code that streams the resource gets run

Comment: May I ask what platform and .NET version do you use?  Currently, I cannot reproduce your issue as I can get the table items in the database using ```Database.Table<tablename>().ToListAsync();``` based on your code. You may first check if your database is empty. Here is the doc: [.NET MAUI local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0)

Comment: ```when I try to perform operations on the database``` Could you please share us the code about how you perform the operations? Or provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).